# Kendo UI Default Grid Filter value

Tags: javascript, razor, kendo-ui

I am trying to default a Kendo UI grid to be filtered on page load. I have a column with boolean values that I need to only display the ones with "false" on page load but allow the user to see them all if they clear filters.

Example: http://www.telerik.com/forums/adding-filters-to-grid-s-source

```
    function updateSearchFilters(grid, field, operator, value) {
        var newFilter = { field: field, operator: operator, value: value };
        var dataSource = grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
        var filters = null;
        if ( dataSource.filter() != null){
            filters = dataSource.filter().filters;
        }       
        if ( filters == null ) {
            filters = [newFilter];
        }
        else {
            var isNew = true;
            var index = 0;
            for(index=0; index < filters.length; index++) {
                if (filters[index].field == field) {
                    isNew = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( isNew){
                filters.push(newFilter);
            }
            else {
                filters[index] = newFilter;
            }
        }
        dataSource.filter(filters);
    }
```

I have tried this solution to call a function on the DataBound event but when the user clears the filter and then tries to group or set other filters, this filter reappears. I am using Razor syntax in the view and was hoping there would be something to set there.

**Update:** For the time being, I have wrapped the example function in an if on a class level variable that is set to true/false based on if it has been called before but I feel like this is a primitive solution.

```
    function onDataBind(grid, field, operator, value){
        if(!alreadyFiltered) //class level variable that is set to true after dataSource.filter(filters);
            updateSearchFilters(grid, field, operator, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you be making it more complicated than necessary.  Can't you just put the filter on your datasource definition?  Then, when bound to the grid, the column is filtered.  Then, using the UI, the user can still clear this filter - your datasource definition just sets it initially.

Comment: To add to my initial comment, something like: filter: { field: "YourColumn", operator: "equals", value: false } for your datasource configuration.

Comment: You've pointed me in the right direction, this is what I'm looking for. But as stated in the question I am using razor syntax so the Filter extension does not take in a JSON array. It takes in `Action<DataSourceFilterDescriptorFactory<SecurityMinorTypeViewModel>>()` and I'm finding it hard to find any documentation around what this is exactly.

Comment: Another piece of information I was missing earlier is that I am using Telerik dlls. I suggest putting your comment as the answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updating my initial comment to an answer.  Essentially, if you define your datasource with the filter, that will define the datasource in its initial state and the user will still be able to change the filter using the UI/Controls as normal.

For a javascript implementation, this might look like this:

```
dataSource: {
    // ... other config
    filter: { field: "YourColumn", operator: "equals", value: false }
}
```

If you are using the column menu filtering, this filter will show up for the user to change - you have only defined its initial state.

You mentioned that you are using the MVC implementation.  I haven't used those helpers before.  I would expect that it would just be a matter of using a similar configuration method, but to your point, the documentation doesn't seem to be clear.  I would start here:

http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#filter

So, maybe it ends up looking something like this:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource            
    .Filter(filters =>
    {       
        filters.Add(f => f.YourColumn).Equals(false);
    }
```

Comment: This was exactly it. Thank you.

Comment: I need to load filters based on storing data in the asp.net session on the server. Can I load the filter values into the ViewBag, dump them into hidden inputs and then load them into the kendo grid datasource?

Comment: @tnk479 - you might want to post a separate question instead of burying it in these comments.  But, at a high level, I think you have a couple of options.  If you are using the MVC helpers, like above, you could do it in your C# controller code.  Or, with a razor view, you could generate the necessary javascript.  I don't think you need to bother with inputs.

Comment: Thanks @snow_FFFFFF. I am not using the MVC helpers but I was also thinking about generating json data in the razor view. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: This solution permanently applies the selected filter, if a user applies their own filter it will apply BOTH, not override one with the other.

Comment: @GreySage - it adds the filter as a user editable filter - so, it is available for the user to interact with as they please.  They can keep it, change it, remove it, etc.  It is not permanent as you state.

Comment: @snow_FFFFFF Yes, it is. I dealt with this exact situation last week (which is why I commented), if you set a filter in the dataSource then the user can't see it and can't change it, any filters they apply are ON TOP of the pre-set filter. There are examples out there of how to solve this for mode=row, but if mode=menu it's even harder. I had to add a function to onFilter to remove the filter in the dataSource if the user applied a filter on the same column. It was a pain.

Comment: @GreySage - having a filter that is editable by the user was the entire point of the original question and the reason for this answer.  I do this all of the time and it works exactly as I describe it.  Here is an example: https://dojo.telerik.com/ocaWuMuX - this grid starts off with the City column filtered, but it is available in the UI to be modified (the grid even indicates that there is a filter applied to the column), just like I described.  You are obviously doing something different - if you have an issue, maybe post your own question instead of erroneously attacking valid answers.